Are there contributed Mathematica programs which yield the normal form and Lyapunov coefficients of an ODE at a bifurcation point, in dimens 3 or more
Despite the very numerous times this computation (see for example normal forms and Lyapunov exponents in Guckenheimer and P. Holmes.Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of
Vector Fields) has been performed in the mathematics literature, it seems that neither does Mathematica offer it, nor is there a contributed script for it, even in dimension 2! To fill this gap,  I found and modified a bit  a symbolic script for  dimension 2, offered by Balasz Boros, with further help from Rafik Zeraoulia, so that now the normal form is outputed also.
(*The first focal value for planar differential equations

has an explicit formula in terms of the derivatives *)
L1Planar[fg_,var_,equilcon]:=
Module[{J,xyshift,Tm,Tinvuv,FG,derivatives,a,b,i,j,L1,x,y,F,G,normForm},
    {x,y}=var;
    (*Jacobian at equilibrium*)
    J=Simplify[D[fg,{var}]/. equilcon];

    (*Shift variables to equilibrium*)
    xyshift={x->x+(x/. equilcon),y->y+(y/. equilcon)};
    (*Transformation matrix*)
    Tm={{1,0},{-a/Global`ome,-b/Global`ome}};
    Tinvuv=Inverse[Tm] . {Global`u,Global`v};
    (*Transformed FG*)
    FG=(Tm . fg/. xyshift)/. {x->Tinvuv[[1]],y->Tinvuv[[2]]}/. {a->J[[1,1]],b->J[[1,2]]};
    (*Compute derivatives*)
    derivatives={};
    For[i=0,i<=3,i++,For[j=0,j<=3-i,j++,derivatives=Join[derivatives,{Subscript[F,i,j]->(D[FG[[1]],{Global`u,i},{Global`v,j}]/. {Global`u->0,Global`v->0}),Subscript[G,i,j]->(D[FG[[2]],{Global`u,i},{Global`v,j}]/. {Global`u->0,Global`v->0})}]]];
    (*Compute L1 coefficient*)
    L1=Subscript[F,3,0]+Subscript[F,1,2]+Subscript[G,0,3]+Subscript[G,2,1]+1/Global`ome*(Subscript[F,1,1]*(Subscript[F,2,0]+Subscript[F,0,2])-Subscript[G,1,1]*(Subscript[G,2,0]+Subscript[G,0,2])+Subscript[F,0,2]*Subscript[G,0,2]-Subscript[F,2,0]*Subscript[G,2,0]);
    (*Substitute derivatives into L1*)
    L1=L1/. derivatives;
    (*Construct the normal form up to cubic terms*)
    F1=Sum[Subscript[F,i,j] Global`u^i Global`v^j,{i,0,3},{j,0,3-i}];
    G1=Sum[Subscript[G,i,j] Global`u^i Global`v^j,{i,0,3},{j,0,3-i}];
    normForm={F1,G1}/. derivatives;
    (*Return L1 coefficient and normal form*)
    {L1,FG,normForm}
    ];

This give the right answer in the example below.
RHS = {(s x1 \[Delta]1 (1 - \[Lambda]1/s))/(a1 + s), 

s (1 - s/K) - (s x1)/(a1 + s)}; var = {x1, s};
so = Solve[RHS == 0, var] //
FullSimplify; Print["The Keener chemostat RHS ",
RHS // MatrixForm, " has ", so // Length, " fixed pts", so];
jac = Grad[RHS, var] /. so[[2]] // FullSimplify;
Print["jac at E1 is", jac // MatrixForm];
{co1, co2, co3} =
CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[jac, z], z] // FullSimplify;
Print["The trace is ", tr = Numerator[Together[co2]] // Factor];
Print["Hopf condition cH is ", cH = Solve[tr == 0, K][[1]]];
Print["eigenvalues under cH are",
eval = FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[jac /. cH]]];
om = eval[[2]]/I // Simplify;
Print["omega square is", om2 = om^2 // FullSimplify];
Lp = L1Planar[(RHS /. cH), var, (so[[2]] /. cH)] // FullSimplify;
Print["L1, after plugging ome -> om, is",
L1 = Lp[[1]] /. {ome^2 -> om2, ome -> om} // FullSimplify];
Print["Normal form up to cubic terms is ",
Series[Lp[[3]] /. {ome^2 -> om2, ome -> om}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] //
Normal // FullSimplify];
So, with help from forum, we are done for dimension 2. Beyond that, the outstanding question  is finding the  Lyapunov exponent in dimension larger than 2 (the exponent is explicit in dimension 2 and probably in any dimension, but I couldn't find it anywhere in the literature). This seems task in which ideally more competent programmers than me should be involved.

Playing a bit with this, I think something might be amiss. If you switch the order of the variables you get a different result for the vanishing trace condition. Maybe there's a flaw in my reasoning but I think that's unexpected.

Interesting observation, but it is not clear this is a problem. The RHS is the vector field for (x',s'), probably arranging the var in a different order gives rise to an ``illegal Jacobian". I am a novice to this topic, but my question of "is there someone else in the world that thinks it worth to program bifurcation computations symbolically" may still be valid.

Indeed, this needs to be erased

Following O.Kuznetsova (2010/2012), I got -((\[Pi] Sqrt[(\[Delta]1 \[Lambda]1)/(a1+2 \[Lambda]1)])/(2 \[Delta]1 \[Lambda]1 (a1+\[Lambda]1))) for L1, which has the same sign as zeraoulia's, I believe. Is it incorrect?

I know there are several equivalent (as far as sign) definitions, and it will take me a time to check.  Is your method from  Computation of Lyapunov quantities and limit cycles.
OA Kuznetsova, GA Leonov - IFAC Proceedings Volumes, 2010  ?

Sorry, I lost the link in a Mma crash. It may have been her thesis, dated 2011 not 2010. From 2008, a series of papers by Kuznetsova, with or without her supervisor Leonov, refine symbolic computation of Lyapunov constants (in MATLAB or Maple); I didn't read them all. I worked from K. 2012 and checked against the other paper and Boros et al. 2018. I didn't consult K./L. 2010, to which I didn't find a free link.

I have no method but Let's refine the script you provided to ensure it handles the computation of the L1 coefficient and the normal form correctly. I'll integrate improvements while maintaining the structure and logic of your original code:
Clear[L1Planar]
L1Planar[fg_, var_, equilcon_ : {}] := Module[
  {J, xyshift, Tm, Tinvuv, FG, derivatives, a, b, i, j, L1, x, y, F, G, normForm},
  
  (* Variables *)
  {x, y} = var;
  
  (* Jacobian at equilibrium *)
  J = Simplify[D[fg, {var}] /. equilcon];
  
  (* Shift variables to equilibrium *)
  xyshift = {x -> x + (x /. equilcon), y -> y + (y /. equilcon)};
  
  (* Transformation matrix *)
  Tm = {{1, 0}, {-a / Global`ome, -b / Global`ome}};
  Tinvuv = Inverse[Tm] . {Global`u, Global`v};
  
  (* Transform FG *)
  FG = (Tm . fg /. xyshift) 
       /. {x -> Tinvuv[[1]], y -> Tinvuv[[2]]} 
       /. {a -> J[[1, 1]], b -> J[[1, 2]]};
  
  (* Compute derivatives *)
  derivatives = {};
  For[i = 0, i <= 3, i++, 
    For[j = 0, j <= 3 - i, j++, 
      derivatives = Join[derivatives, {
        Subscript[F, i, j] -> (D[FG[[1]], {Global`u, i}, {Global`v, j}] /. {Global`u -> 0, Global`v -> 0}),
        Subscript[G, i, j] -> (D[FG[[2]], {Global`u, i}, {Global`v, j}] /. {Global`u -> 0, Global`v -> 0})
      }]
    ]
  ];
  
  (* Compute L1 coefficient *)
  L1 = Subscript[F, 3, 0] + Subscript[F, 1, 2] + Subscript[G, 0, 3] + Subscript[G, 2, 1] + 
       1/Global`ome * (Subscript[F, 1, 1] * (Subscript[F, 2, 0] + Subscript[F, 0, 2]) - 
                       Subscript[G, 1, 1] * (Subscript[G, 2, 0] + Subscript[G, 0, 2]) +
                       Subscript[F, 0, 2] * Subscript[G, 0, 2] - Subscript[F, 2, 0] * Subscript[G, 2, 0]);
  
  (* Substitute derivatives into L1 *)
  L1 = L1 /. derivatives;
  
  (* Construct the normal form up to cubic terms *)
  F = Sum[Subscript[F, i, j] Global`u^i Global`v^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3 - i}];
  G = Sum[Subscript[G, i, j] Global`u^i Global`v^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3 - i}];
  
  normForm = {F, G} /. derivatives;
  
  (* Return L1 coefficient and normal form *)
  {L1, FG, derivatives, normForm}
];

(* Example usage *)
RHS = {(s x1 \[Delta]1 (1 - \[Lambda]1/s))/(a1 + s), 
       s (1 - s/K) - (s x1)/(a1 + s)};
var = {x1, s};
so = Solve[RHS == 0, var] // FullSimplify;

Print["The Keener chemostat RHS ", RHS // MatrixForm, " has ", so // Length, " fixed pts", so];

jac = Grad[RHS, var] /. so[[2]] // FullSimplify;
Print["jac at E1 is", jac // MatrixForm];

{co1, co2, co3} = CoefficientList[CharacteristicPolynomial[jac, z], z] // FullSimplify;
Print["The trace is ", tr = Numerator[Together[co2]] // Factor];

Print["Hopf condition cH is ", cH = Solve[tr == 0, K][[1]]];
Print["eigenvalues under cH are", eval = FullSimplify[Eigenvalues[jac /. cH]]];
om = eval[[2]]/I // Simplify;
Print["omega square is", om2 = om^2 // FullSimplify];

Lp = L1Planar[(RHS /. cH), var, (so[[2]] /. cH)] // FullSimplify;
Print["L1, after plugging ome -> om, is", L1 = Lp[[1]] /. ome^2 -> om2 // FullSimplify];
Print["Normal form up to cubic terms is ", Lp[[4]]];



Thanks! I also checked and the script is fine, especially with the extra comments provided.  The only outstanding questions are how come such a useful script is only available in a github site https://github.com/balazsboros/reaction_networks/tree/main/3reactions  and whether the three dimensional script also provided there can be adapted to more dimensions. Rafik, if you agree, I will copy paste your version into a bifurcations package I'm developping

OOps, unfortunately there's a loop now "$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded."

@florin I agree to have my version of the code copied and pasted into your bifurcation package.

Your code gives TerminatedEvaluation[RecursionLimit] as an answer, which is not a good answer. You don't even show your answer, which makes it seem like you're hiding the failing of the code. Please strive to give high-quality answers, if you can. Thanks.

This is not an answer to the question or at least only a partial one. It may help to get started though. A Hopf bifurcation at an equilibrium, if I understand correctly, happens when the Jacobian has a pair of conjugate eigenvalues with zero real part, so of the form {I*t,-I*t} for some real value t. If the characteristic polynomial charpoly of the matrix is in a new variable lambda then this means it has a pair of factors {lambda+I*t,lambda-I*t}, which in turn means charpoly is divisible by lambda^2+t^2. So we can use this to obtain some conditions for such a bifurcation to arise.
Here is an example I contrived, simple enough to analyze but of dimention higher than 2 so that we have to do actual work at the divisibility step. The ODE variables are {x,y,z} and there are a few symbolic parameters as well. I start by solving the right hand side of the ODE system to find the equilibrium point(s).
vars = {x, y, z};
rhspolys = {a*x*z (1 - b/y) - 1, c*y/x + 1, d*x + y^2};
equilib = Solve[rhspolys == 0, vars]

(* Out[172]= {{x -> -c^2 d, y -> c d, z -> 1/(a c (b - c d))}} *)

Compute the Jacobian at the equilibrium point:
eq = equilib[[1]];
equilibJac = Grad[rhspolys, vars] /. eq

(* Out[182]= {{(1 - b/(c d))/(
  c (b - c d)), -(b/(c d (b - c d))), -a c^2 (1 - b/(c d)) d}, {-(1/(
   c^2 d)), -(1/(c d)), 0}, {d, 2 c d, 0}} *)

Obtain the characteristic polynomial.
charpoly = 
 Numerator@Together@CharacteristicPolynomial[equilibJac, lam]

(* Out[184]= 
a b^2 c^2 d - 2 a b c^3 d^2 + a c^4 d^3 - lam - a b^2 c^3 d^2 lam + 
 2 a b c^4 d^3 lam - a c^5 d^4 lam + b lam^2 + b c lam^2 - c d lam^2 -
  c^2 d lam^2 + b c^2 d lam^3 - c^3 d^2 lam^3 *)

We now divide by a symbolic quadratic representing lam^2+t^2. It's slightly simpler to call the squared symbolic constant tsq. We find the constant and linear parts of the remainder term. Recall that these need to vanish in order to satisfy the divisibility condition.
{quo, rem} = 
  PolynomialQuotientRemainder[charpoly, lam^2 + tsq, lam];
{const, lin} = CoefficientList[rem, lam]

(* Out[186]= {a b^2 c^2 d - 2 a b c^3 d^2 + a c^4 d^3 - b tsq - b c tsq +
   c d tsq + c^2 d tsq, -1 - a b^2 c^3 d^2 + 2 a b c^4 d^3 - 
  a c^5 d^4 - b c^2 d tsq + c^3 d^2 tsq} *)

Now solve for the remainder to vanish. I'll use one of the parameters as well as tsq for the variables to find.
conditions = Solve[{const, lin} == 0, {tsq, a}]

(* Out[178]= {{tsq -> 1/(c (1 + 2 c) d (-b + c d)), 
  a -> -((1 + c)/(c^3 (1 + 2 c) d^2 (-b + c d)^2))}} *)

This gives tsq and, since that must be positive, we get an implied further condition that 1/(c (1 + 2 c) d (-b + c d)) > 0.
I think with this approach one can solve for cases where parameter values will give rise to a Hopf bifurcation. The algebra can get messy though.

Thanks, this may be indeed an alternate way to proceed for dimensions larger than 2, which is the real issue. More precisely, one part of the computation, the Hopf condition  is  easy in several equivalent ways: use Routh Hurwitz, or Equate to zero the resultant of the real and imaginary parts of the characteristic polynomial at i w, or your approach, which appears also in a book by Romanovski on polynomial systems. The difficult part is proceeding to find the first Lyapunov exponent (this is explicit in dimension 2 and probably in any dimension, but I couldn't find this in the literature)
